# Single Item Array Read as Object in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, webpack

I'm hoping someone can help me bug fix an issue I'm having where an array that contains a single item is read as an object in json data. I'm using `.map`to loop over the values like defined here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html

The build I'm using is: https://github.com/newtriks/generator-react-webpack, so I'm not sure if this is a webpack issue, `fetch` issue (how I'm requesting the data), or something much more obvious. Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In JS arrays are objects. Run this snippet in your browser: `var arr = [1,2,3]; typeof arr;`

Answer (score 0):

I found where the error was. I was using YQL as a proxy service to get around CORS. Turns out the default response is “lossy”, where single element arrays are returned as an object.. had me scratching my head for a while trying to figure out where this was coming from. Solution was to add `jsonCompat=new` to the query string. Listed in the docs here: https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/response.html#json-to-json-transformation